# Would you find it nice if I start to make self-answered questions about basic geology?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

[It is encouraged by stack](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

I am planning to make questions from time to time about basics geology and answer myself if nobody does before they fall down on the list.

[I wrote the first one to leave you an example](https://earthscience.stackexchange.com/questions/16562/whats-the-difference-between-cleavage-and-exfoliation). It is obvious I know the difference between cleavage and fracture, but the trick is to post it, wait a bit and if there is no answer in one or two days answer it myself.

I think it could attract more students to the site, also help students searching directly from Google searcher and, of course, you could also profit it to make complementary or better answers than mine.

Comment: In general, I think it's fine to post basic questions.  However, if the post shows no evidence of independent research, then it usually is not something that meets posting guidelines.  A good posted question presents information; it's not meant to be just a homework question.

Answer (score 3):

I would find it nice and I would encourage it too. However, to make a real contribution I would suggest that you should be very selective with the questions, and refrain from posting questions for which an answer can be found easily with an online search.

Comment: I will try to make accurated questions not so obvious to answer.

Answer (score 2):

In principle this is fine, but doing this specifically to populate the site may lead to very odd questions that don't feel natural or really work here.

So my advice is "don't try to think about what basic questions you could ask and answer; instead, think about what questions puzzled you when you were learning earth science, and post those". In other words, make them real questions that you've had in the past.

Answer (score 0):

I think, after the task of closing id-question is done, I will only log here to ask questions when my mineral app is published in some months, but not to answer, so no self-answered questions. English is a barrier, I am tired of consulting Google Translate, and students deserve better answers that i can offer.

Thanks @Camilo Rada and @Semidiurnal Simon. That make me think on how should I ask. I putted two or three questions on the hot list recently. I will search for interesting questions for geology students. Maybe I can atract some of them to my guide.

Thanks to let me edit the uncorrectly taged questions. Don't forget to do it and to edit the students questions pointing at the title to keywords on the subject, so students find all those very nice answers and learn. Google has a tool to realize what terms students search more (https://ads.google.com/intl/es_es/home/tools/keyword-planner/)

I will just post a monthly question or so. If the question is bad, just downvote it,so I will delete it.